# Is it possible to pass environment variables to a newly created user?

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables, gitlab

In my GitLab CI script, I am creating a new user which then executes a command. I'm noticing that when the command is executed as this user, the CI environment variables aren't available.

Below is what I do:

```
before_script:
   - useradd -U -d "$CI_PROJECT_DIR" newuser

test-app:
  stage: test
  image: open-jdk
  script:
    - echo $MY_CI_VAR #here I can see the env var set in GitLab CI
    - su newuser -l -c "grails test-app -unit FooHelper" #in the code it is not available
```

**Question**

Is there a way to pass environment variables either when creating a new user or when executing a command as that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the command you're executing is run as a different user with `su` which by default doesn't bring your environment. You specify the `-l` option which will clear the environment variables before switching to the other user. You can drop the `-l` option and use `-m` instead to preserve the environment.

Try this:
`- su newuser -m -c "grails test-app -unit FooHelper"`

You may need to set the full path to `grails` because your `PATH` is an environment variable that won't get set to `newuser`'s PATH.

You may also be able to pass it into the command if you need to keep the login shell. 
`- su newuser -l -c "MY_CI_VAR=$MY_CI_VAR grails test-app -unit FooHelper"`